# How do i terminate my script if i don't get an expected integer value? - BASH Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

as i explained in the title, i need to terminate the exec. of my script if the input value is not an integer. Im getting the number from a positional parameter. Here is the code:

```
a=9
kb=0
var=$2
var=${var:3:1}
if [ ${#2} -ne 4 ]
then
    echo "ethN is wrong"
    exit 1
fi
if [ "$var" -gt 10  -o "$var" -lt 0 ]
then
    echo "N is wrong"
    exit 1
else
    echo "N is ok"
fi
```

when i use this entry:

> bash lartc.sh -i eth#

My script is not ending and i want it to because the "#" from eth# is not an integer and this is what i want it to do. (e.g of valid input: eth2,eth3,etc...). However, my terminal says to me that "#" was expected to be an int. I'm validating length and that the number must be between 0-9, i just need to validate the type of it. Any ideas? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `=~` operator to chech whether N is positive integer or not.

`stringA =~ regexp` stringA matches the extended regular expression regexp. Only available in bash version 3.0 and later. May only be used inside [[...]]. The =~ Regular Expression match operator no longer requires quoting
of the pattern within [[ … ]]. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver3.html

```
var=${var:3}

if [[ ! $var =~ ^[1-9][0-9]*$ ]]
then
    echo "ethN is wrong"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thank you all for helping me, i was a little busy with college, that's why i'm replying now but i did use your suggestions! This one worked just fine for me. (I also tested the one who user Quinn said and it worked too) Thank you all, we keep rockin! lml

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to validate the N in a certain position is an integer, the following approach should be good:

```
#! /bin/sh
var=$2
result=$(echo ${var} | grep -E "eth[0-9]")

if [ -z "${result}" ]; then 
    echo "N is wrong"
    exit 1
else 
    echo 'N is ok'
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bash, why not just test against `[[ $2 =~ "^eth[0-9]$" ]]`? If that is true, you know:

- The input has four characters because of `^` and `$`
- The first three letters are `eth`
- The last is a digit

What will you do if someone runs this on a systemd linux and tries to match enp4s0? :P